# Targeting different database systems with EF6 (and Code First Migrations)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

My project (WPF, .Net 4.5, EF6) has to target different DBMS, so far it's MSSQL, Oracle, MySql and Firebird.
I started with creating dbs-dependent scripts that generate the database(s) and then used Entity Frameworks Database-First-approach to create the models. By having a default edmx based on MSSQL and creating separate ssdls for the other providers (the differing ssdl-files can be configured in the connection strings) it all worked pretty good for all dbms.
The problem I see now is maintaining installation/updates for 4 or more different dbms for even many more customers. We won't send admins to install updates at our customers, we rather need something like a generic setup/update routine for all. It's possible but you would have to maintain different versions of sql scripts for each dbms and kind of a setup tool that handles those scripts and knows which to execute for which database (depending on dbms and current version).

When looking for alternatives I came across EF Code First Migrations and tried switching to this approach. My tries are based on MSSQL and MySql so far.

It all works good when I stick to either MSSQL or MySql. Creating migrations, applying them to existing or non-exisiting databases, all this works pretty fine.
But I'm stuck with bringing both system together. Applying MSSQL-based migrations to MySql for example seems to be impossible. The database will be created but it's not possible to connect due to type mismatches and so on.
My guess is that the "__Migration"-Table contains a model which was created based on MSSQL and is incompatible with the MySql-provider now. Just a theory but maybe someone knows better.

Does anyone know a solution for this? Is there any way to target different dbms with EF?
I can't believe that I am the only one with this problem but it's really hard to find any information about this.
Any help is appreciated, even directing me to other approaches than using EF that way or using EF at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same situation, but I found simple workaround for that. Everything you need is just create seperate projects for each database system with enabled migration. In your case, two database contexts should inherit from one base context where all model builders and DbSets are kept.

Example model:

```cs
// MyModel.Base.csproj
public class Person { /*..*/ }

public class BaseDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    /*...*/
}

// MyModel.Sql.csproj

public class SqlDbContext : BaseDbContext {}

// MyModel.MySql.csproj

public class MySqlDbContext : BaseDbContext {}
```

Maybe having two migrations settings it's not so awesome idea, but you are able to use some database-specific scripts in your migrations.